# How to get the NONSTOP hp db driver?

Tags: python, hp-nonstop

[How can I connect to a sql/mp or sql/mx database on Nonstop using python.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60975215/how-can-i-connect-to-a-sql-mp-or-sql-mx-database-on-nonstop-using-python/61692347#61692347)

i have followed this to get the connection established to HP nonstop database, I am getting error as driver DRIVER={NonStop ODBC/MX 3.6} is not found.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you confirm that you installed the driver following the procedures described in the [NonStop ODBC/MX Client Drivers User Guide](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=a00045523en_us&docLocale=en_US) and that you have version 3.6 not another version ?

Comment: I am working off the server and trying to connect to the NONSTOP Sql server, 
   I am not able to get the driver, as shown in the user guid.                                    
          I am unable to understand step 4.Use FTP to download the following files from the $SYSTEM.ZMXODBC installation subvolume:•  ANSI TDMODBC or the Unicode ODBCW32 file for 32–bit driver install•  ANSI NSODBC64 or the Unicode ODBCW64 file for 64–bit driver install

Answer (score 0):

To connect the NonStop sql or for any relevant databases, a ODBC or JDBC driver is required.

From my experience JDBC works with JAVA only thought there are pyodbc and other python libs are available( they didn't work for me and they internally depends on java.)

Better to do it in java. In my case I called the java class from python using os level commands and result stored in excel which is read from python again.

Answer (score 0):

for this I use jpype:

```
import jpype
import jpype.imports
from jpype.types import *
from jpype import JString
driver_jar_path = "C:\\develop\\automation\\libraries\\t4sqlmx-3.8.1.jar"
jvmPath = jpype.getDefaultJVMPath()
args='-Djava.class.path=%s' % driver_jar_path
jpype.startJVM(jvmPath, args)
from java.util import EnumSet
from java.util.logging import Level
from java.util.logging import Logger
from java.sql import SQLException
from java.util import Properties
from com.tandem.t4jdbc import SQLMXDriver
my_properties = Properties()
my_properties.setProperty("user", "myuser")
my_properties.setProperty("password", "mypassword")
my_properties.setProperty("catalog", "CAT_SOMETHING")
my_properties.setProperty("schema", "SOMETHING_ALIAS")
my_driver = SQLMXDriver()
conn = my_driver.connect(JString("jdbc:t4sqlmx://myaddress:1234"), my_properties)
stmt = conn.createStatement()
stmt.executeQuery("""...
```